# Generic function with generic class: no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, generics, implicit

I'm trying to cleanup some duplicate code blocks by introducing a generic function. But I don't manage to do so and I have the feeling that my class inheritance structure is becoming messier than the code I'm trying to clean...

Here's an abstract overview of the classes involved:

interfaces:

```
interface Ia
interface Ib : Ia
interface Ic : Ib
```

classes:

```
class Ca<T> where T : Ia
class Cb<T> : Ca<T> where T : Ia
class Cc : Cb<Ic>
```

function:

```
void F<T>(T t) where T : Ca<Ib>
```

invalid function call:

```
F<Cc>(my_c);
```

error:

`The type 'Cc' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'F<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Cc' to 'Ca<Ib>'.`

I guessed the word 'implicit' in the error my refer to the fact that there is no `where T : Ib` in the class definitions. So I added another class

```
class Cb2<T> : Cb<T> where T : Ib
```

and made `Cc` inherit from `Cb2` instead of `Cb`. But this resulted in the same error.

Can anyone explain why this is restricted, and how I could solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this code works, you'll need to use a interface to enable covariance as Pavel said before. You need only one at highest level.

```
interface ICa<out T> where T : Ia
class Ca<T> : ICa<T> where T : Ia
class Cb<T> : Ca<T> where T : Ia
class Cc : Cb<Ic>
```

The method signature should be this way

```
void F<T>(T t) where T : ICa<Ib>
```

Comment: I guess you mean `interface ICa`. This solves my problem, thanks. Question remains whether the extra interface level at the top of the inheritance line is cleaner than a duplicate block of code... :)

Answer (score 2):

In general C# doesn't alow generic parameter substitution even if they are inherited classes. This changed when [variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx.) modifiers were added.

What you need is called covariance it enables using derived types in place of generic parameter. But variance modifiers work only on interface and delegates so `Ca`, `Cb`, `Cc` should be interfaces to allow this. So closest you can get with it is:

```
interface Ia {}
interface Ib : Ia {}
interface Ic : Ib {}

interface Ca<out T> where T : Ia {}
interface Cb<out T> : Ca<T> where T : Ia {}
interface Cc : Cb<Ic> {}

class Main
{
    void F<T>(T t) where T : Ca<Ib>
    {}

    void M()
    {
      F<Cc>(null);
    }
}
```

Notice `out T` in `Ca` and `Cb` definition.

[More about out modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Small question: will these variance modifiers have performance impact, or is it just a compile-time thing?

Comment: Compile time, but they put some restrictions on interface members to allow run time type safety.